# Seq2Seq Models for Chatbots

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, chatbot, machine-translation, sequence-to-sequence

I am building a chat-bot with a sequence to sequence encoder decoder model as in [NMT](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt). From the data given I can understand that when training they feed the decoder outputs into the decoder inputs along with the encoder cell states. I cannot figure out that when i am actually deploying a chatbot in real time, how what should I input into the decoder since that time is the output that i have to predict. Can someone help me out with this please?

Comment: I am also follow that https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt and I have same problem like that can you find solusion??

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer depends on which building blocks you take from [Neural Machine Translation model](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt) (NMT) and which ones you would replace with your own. I assume the graph structure exactly as in NMT.

If so, at inference time, you can feed just a vector of zeros to the decoder.

---

**Internal details**: NMT uses the entity called `Helper` to determine the next input in the decoder (see [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.Helper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/Helper) documentation).

In particular, [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BasicDecoder) relies solely on helper when it performs a step: the `next_inputs` that the are fed in to the subsequent cell is exactly the return value of `Helper.next_inputs()`.

There are different implementations of `Helper` interface, e.g.,

- [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/TrainingHelper) is returning the next decoder input (which is usually ground truth). This helper is used in training as indicated in [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq#decoder).
- [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/GreedyEmbeddingHelper) discards the inputs, and returns the `argmax` sampled token from the previous output. NMT uses this helper in inference when `sampling_temperature` hyper-parameter is 0.
- [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.SampleEmbeddingHelper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/SampleEmbeddingHelper) does the same, but samples the token according to [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) (a.k.a. generalized Bernoulli) distribution. NMT uses this helper in inference when `sampling_temperature > 0`.
- ...

The code is in [`BaseModel._build_decoder`](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/model.py#L358) method.
Note that both `GreedyEmbeddingHelper` and `SampleEmbeddingHelper` don't care what the decoder input is. So in fact you can feed anything, but the zero tensor is the standard choice.

Comment: If we feed in a vector of zeros as the 'start token' at inference time, do we need to prepend zeros to the target words during the training process for consistency?

Comment: In inference, in contrast with training, the input vector is not used. In training it is used, so it must be sensible

Comment: So e.g., if a single example of my tokenized training inputs are [1,2,3,4], should I add the start token 0 to the training inputs to make them [0,1,2,3,4] for correct behaviour? Given that we prepend zeros to the start during inference?